# Saving a MATLAB plot via commands

Tags: matlab, save, plot

I am using MATLAB via PuTTY , which obviously means I can't view plots. Is there a way to create plots and save them as a file so I can download them via FTP?

Comment: I taught it was possible to run PuTTY with X forwarding, so you can run matlab with graphics. Have you tried this?

Comment: That's amazing :O I wish I'd known about this before. Totally works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) option. If you need to save it as an EPS, use

```
print(h,'-depsc',filename)
```

where `h` is your figure handle. For other rasterized formats like JPEG, PNG, etc, you can specify resolution as

```
print(h,'-djpeg','-r150',filename)
```

You have more formats to choose from, which are documented in the help file.